# Plotly.js: How to set string title on the points

Tags: plotly.js, ticker

I am quite a starter in Plotly.js.
I am very sorry to ask like maybe basic question.

On a scatter3d graph, default ticker on the points shows their axis numbers, like "x:1 y:1 z:1".

I wanna show it other name, like "a"<-"x:1 y:1 z:1", "b"<-"x:2 y:2 z:2"...

Which attribute does work for it?

"ticktext" did not work.:<

ex.

```
var data = [
    {
        opacity: 0.5,
        type: 'scatter3d',
        x: [1,2,3],
        y: [1,2,3],
        z: [1,2,3],
        mode: 'markers'
    }
];
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Using `text`, for example:

```
    .
    .
x:[1,2,3],
y:[1,2,3],
z:[1,2,3],
text:["a","b","c"],
    .
    .
```

Reference: https://plotly.com/javascript/text-and-annotations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).